# How to get MSBuild pack to consider the packageId of referenced project?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, pack

I have a .NET Framework solution that publishes several NuGet packages. The project files are using PackageReference, plus some of the projects to be packaged are referencing each other. One of the projects has a different PackageId than the library name set in the project file as a property.
When packing that project, this alternative packageId works perfectly, but when going for a package referencing this project, the generated nuspec file contains the original project name as a dependency.

Is there any way to get the package contain the overwritten Id without having to manually write the nuspec file?

Example:
OldName.csproj has PackageId set to "NewNameDependency"
NewName.csproj has PackageId set to "NewName" and references OldName.csproj
msbuild OldName.csproj -t:pack creates package "NewNameDependency"
msbuild NewName.csproj -t:pack creates package NewName, but in the generated nuspec the dependency is OldName.csproj